# K non-isomorphic graphs with the same size and order

Tags: graph-theory

I am having a hard time with the following problem:

For every positive integer k ≥ 2, give an example of k simple, non-isomorphic graphs with the same size and the same order.

I would appreciate any help, thanks :D

Comment: Can you explain/define what size and order mean in this context?

Comment: Does size refer to the number of vertices and order to the number of edges?

Comment: Yes, Jake is right, the size is the number of vertices and the order is the number of the edges of the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (maybe boring) solution. Given $k\geq 2$, we construct $k$ graphs with $2k$ vertices and $k$ edges in the following way:

Label the vertices $\{v_1,\dots,v_{2k}\}$. For the first graph, let the edges be $$\{(v_1,v_2),(v_3,v_4),(v_5,v_6),\dots,(v_{2k-4},v_{2k-3}),(v_{2k-2},v_{2k-1})\}.$$ (To make sure you are seeing this right, note that each vertex has order 1.) Let the edges of the second graph be $$\{(v_1,v_2),(v_2,v_3),(v_5,v_6),\dots,(v_{2k-2},v_{2k-1})\}.$$ (Here, $v_2$ has order 2 and $v_4$ has order 0; the other vertices have order 1.) The $k$-th graph should have edges $$\{(v_1,v_2),(v_2,v_3),(v_3,v_4),\dots,(v_{k-1},v_k)\}.$$

The proof that these are nonisomorphic I leave as an exercise.

**Here's a fun question when you're done:** In my example, I used $2k$ vertices to produce the $k$ graphs. Could I have used fewer? What's the best I could do?

Comment: Thank you!! Could you give me a hint as to why they are non-isomorphic?

Comment: My hint is to see the parentheses; consider the orders of vertices in each graph.